Connection Error "Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.1'" When Connecting to MySQL Docker Container
I'm having trouble connecting to a MySQL database running inside a Docker container. Here's the setup:
I have created a MySQL Docker container with the following docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpassword
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

volumes:
  mysqldb-volume: {}

The container is up and running. I have verified this with docker ps.
When I try to connect to the MySQL database using MySQL Workbench with the following settings:
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3307
Username: root
Password: [root password]

I receive the following error:
"Connection error! Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.1' (using password: YES)"

I then tried to connect using 172.19.0.1 as the host, but got a different error:
"Connection error! connect ETIMEDOUT"

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to connect to the MySQL database from MySQL Workbench. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing these connection issues and how to resolve them.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Did you change these settings after you first created the container with the volume? That's usually the case with this error. See MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD is set but getting "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" in docker container.
